# PHP Sockets in docker-compose: "socket_connect(): unable to connect"

Tags: php, docker, sockets, docker-compose

I recently upgraded a application from bitnami to docker. i use sockets to connect to a deamon and now it doesnt work anymore. it gives me the error: "socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused". I made a test website and ran it in both bitnami and docker, only docker gives me a error here.

### Test site:

php.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets

COPY home.php /

CMD ["php", "/home.php"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - .:/app
php:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/php.dockerfile
    volumes: 
        - .:/app
```

home.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.google.com');

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.google.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

I got home.php socket test from this code sample https://gist.github.com/md5/f0ca3ba1c2b0f04785fb
In bitnami i only used the home.php file and everything worked fine and i got the expected result while docker gave me the same error, is this something about container networking?